# How do I Install Macaulay2 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, apt

I am trying to install Macaulay2. I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

I have modified `/etc/apt/sources.list` as explained at [the official site](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Ubuntu/index.html) and followed the steps but somehow when I use synaptic package manager it says that cannot load UIUC repositories. When I use apt-get I get the message that it couldn't locate Macaulay2.

Using Gdebi I get this error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable Macaulay 1.5 *
```

I am not sure how I should go about it and any help is highly appreciated.

*: I am running intel i-5 processor and the (architecture) dependent version seems to be i3. But I do not think that is an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions at the [official site](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Ubuntu/index.html) are a little verbose  and hard to follow, so here's how I got `Macaulay2` installed.

**Note:** It is probably best to reverse anything that you have already done and remove anything related to macaulay2, so that the method below will be successful and without errors.

The easiest thing is to put the Macaulay repository in a separate list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. This is what I do with all external, non-Ubuntu repositories.

1) Create and open the list with

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Macaulay2.list
```

2) Now paste into that file the following (For future readers: substitute quantal for your Ubuntu version):

```
deb http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/ubuntu quantal main
```

Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

3) Add the repository key with

```
wget -q http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/PublicKeys/Macaulay2-key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

4) Update your repository lists with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5) As the [official page](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Ubuntu/index.html) mentions, you may need to install `liblapack3gf` as well **before** you install `macaulay2`:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack3gf
```

6) In addition, you may need [libntl-5.4.2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libntl-5.4.2) if you are running Quantal (12.10) or later as it is no longer in that repository. I already had it installed, but you should be ok to install it from the Precise repos as listed above, but just choose the right architecture and use

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```

There are no dependencies to cause any concerns in this case. [Other people](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/macaulay2/DE3_sLq4xcE) running 12.10 have noted that this is also necessary.

7) Now install the program with

```
sudo apt-get install macaulay2
```

**Note:** If `apt-get` keeps failing then download and install the correct files (Macaulay2 and Macaulay2-common) for your architecture manually from [the repository](http://www.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/) and install each with `gdebi` so any further dependencies can be resolved.

8) The command to launch it is `M2` (uppercase M) and the man page can be reached by entering `man M2`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I first cleared all previous entries to uiuc repositories from my /etc/apt/sources.list.d file and then followed your steps. However when trying to install Macaulay2 I am getting this message:N: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'Macaulay2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Unable to locate package Macaulay2

Comment: @DBS Sorry, I missed the `.list` off the file- it will work now.

Comment: When I modified the .list  file and when I do sudo apt-get update it seems to load the uiuc repositories. But when I try to install Macaulay2 it says 'unable to locate macaulay2'.

Comment: @DBS Strange, it did install for me: perhaps you could try to mark it for installation in Synaptic. Go to origin > select the uuic repo and mark macaulay for installation and apply the changes.

Comment: @DBS I think I might have got it- it is perhaps a dependency issue, as `libntl-5.4.2` is no longer in the Quantal repos, but for some reason I have it installed. You should be ok to install it from the Precise repos: see [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libntl-5.4.2), but choose the right architecture.

Comment: sorry for being so bothersome. It still doesn't work. I installed the intel package and installed using gdebi. Then I tried to reload my repositories in Synaptic but no change.

Comment: @DBS It could be an architecture problem if you are running a 64 bit system. I am using 32 bit, and the very latest 32 bit version of the package has also [been confirmed by others](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/macaulay2/GZb5n5pqDf0) to be installable on 12.10. I'm not sure what else to suggest at the minute.

Comment: I see. One question what if I use the precise repos instead of quantal repos. I assume the worst case scenario is that it will crash.... but it might work?

Comment: @DBS See my edit re installing the debs from the repository with `gdebi` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I succesfully installed it following the empiric method I also posted on the [Macaulay2's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=it&fromgroups=#!searchin/macaulay2/ubuntu%242012.10/macaulay2/DE3_sLq4xcE/Ux-YyEV7o9EJ) that I report here:

> 1. Add the repo as described in the official page
> 2. Go [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libntl-5.4.2/5.4.2-4.1build1) and download package libntl-5.4.2 (it is no more present in 12.10)
> 3. Install it (using gDebi, dpkg -i or any other method)
> 4. Install Macaulay2

This method generates a lot of errors like these:

```
Ignoring install-info called from maintainer script
The package macaulay2-common should be rebuilt with new debhelper to  get trigger support
```

Than can be ignored, as described in the reply of that discussion.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but still had some problems. The Macaulay website is unfortunately not very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in my computer the following seems to finally work. I will enlist the steps I took and probably the experts might clarify what is redundant and what is essential.

Please look at Mik's answer above , for details of execution.

Step 1: Updated the Repository list to quantal.
*The instructions on Macaulay website differ from Mik's above. So be careful about that.*

Step2: Get the Key.
*However I tried installing Macaulay2 and it couldn't locate it.*

Step3: Installed the correct version of Macaulay2 (depending on architecture).

*Not that there are two files, the common one (....common.deb) and the processor dependent one (......amd.64.)*

Step4: Install using gdebi-gtk.

Step5: Then use synaptic to load the repos.

It seems to work in my case.