# Help to install Macaulay2

Tags: apt

I am unable to install Macaulay2. I am following the guideline given in the website [M2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Ubuntu/index.html). I have added the repository in the sources list (see the attached screenshot). I have installed the key from the link above. Now when I search for the package with apt-cache search macaylay2 I get nothing.

I have also looked at the answer to [an old related quiestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271039/how-do-i-install-macaulay2-in-ubuntu-12-10) but I don't think that will work either, please help.[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you open https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/ in a browser; you'll note no directory for Bionic - ie. 18.04 isn't supported (yet anyway).   Yeah I realize their page http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Ubuntu/index.html indicates it is; but look yourself & there is nothing there.   (*actually I get a 403 - Forbidden so maybe it's not public*)   This is not a Ubuntu issue, but an issue that needs to be taken up with the creator or faculty.math.illinios.edu

Comment: Sorry didn't think of checking there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the Macauley2 Repository may not be working the Bionic Beaver Debian files work well enough when *downloaded and installed directly*. Install as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas3 libgfortran4 liblapack3 libquadmath0
wget https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb
wget https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-common.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This installed cleanly on my own Bionic system and appears to be functional:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ M2
Macaulay2, version 1.14
--storing configuration for package FourTiTwo in /home/andrew/.Macaulay2/init-FourTiTwo.m2
--storing configuration for package Topcom in /home/andrew/.Macaulay2/init-Topcom.m2
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems, LLLBases, PrimaryDecomposition,
               ReesAlgebra, TangentCone, Truncations

i1 :
```

And hopefully all will be well on your system as well :)

Comment: @mukhujje Great news :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I copied and pasted what you have written into the terminal but for the second and third lines it says ERROR 404: Not Found. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @Artus I have updated for newer version and appropriately updated this brief answer. Tested on my Bionic VM and all is working well, thanks for letting me know my answer had broken :)

Comment: Thanks a lot now the second and third lines work. But when I type M2 it says "M2: command not found". I just noticed that  for the first line it says "404 Not Found" and says "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Comment: @Artus Hmmm.... try running the suggested command lines and try again? That would be: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and if no joy with the first line again add `--fix-missing` into the mix...

Comment: Thanks. I typed the first line again. Then I typed "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" and then the second and third lines. It didn't work. So I typed the first line again and then I typed "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing" and then the second and third lines. It still didn't work. I'm not sure if this is the problem but when I typed "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing" it said "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded". Why does it say "2 not upgraded" is that the issue?

Comment: It works for me for ubuntu 20.04, I replace bionic by focal and Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb by Macaulay2-1.15-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-20.04.deb.