# Problems when installing Macaulay2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I want to install Macaulay2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058118/help-to-install-macaulay2/1058524?noredirect=1) and for some reason its not working. Could anybody help me figure this out? So this is what I have:

Input

```
 sudo apt-get install libblas3 libgfortran4 liblapack3 libquadmath0
```

Output:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 libblas3 is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
 liblapack3 is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
 libgfortran4 is already the newest version (7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1).
 libquadmath0 is already the newest version (8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1).
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Input

```
 wget https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb
```

Output

```
 Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
 ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/artus/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
 --2019-10-30 13:51:17--  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb
 Resolving faculty.math.illinois.edu      (faculty.math.illinois.edu)... 128.174.199.46
 Connecting to faculty.math.illinois.edu   (faculty.math.illinois.edu)|128.174.199.46|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 23695100 (23M) [application/octet-stream]
 Saving to: ‘Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb.7’

 Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Lin 100%[===============================>]  22.60M   425KB/s    in 59s

 2019-10-30 13:52:25 (395 KB/s) - ‘Macaulay2-1.14-amd64-Linux-Ubuntu-18.04.deb.7’ saved [23695100/23695100]
```

Input

```
 wget https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-common.deb
```

Output

```
 Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
 ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/artus/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
 --2019-10-30 13:53:27--  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Macaulay2-1.14-common.deb
 Resolving faculty.math.illinois.edu (faculty.math.illinois.edu)... 128.174.199.46
 Connecting to faculty.math.illinois.edu (faculty.math.illinois.edu)|128.174.199.46|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 21834554 (21M) [application/octet-stream]
 Saving to: ‘Macaulay2-1.14-common.deb.7’

 Macaulay2-1.14-common.de 100%[===============================>]  20.82M   946KB/s    in 43s

 2019-10-30 13:54:19 (499 KB/s) - ‘Macaulay2-1.14-common.deb.7’ saved [21834554/21834554]
```

Input

```
 M2
```

Output

```
 M2: command not found
```

Note: I am using the linux subsystem in windows 10 (not sure if that makes any difference). I would really appreciate any help since I've been trying to install this for over a week and it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Oops, looks like when I re-edited that answer I left out the vital `sudo dpkg *.deb` that actually installs the 2 Debian packages!! Apologies...

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks I will try that.

Comment: @andrew.46 Sorry for bothering you but when I type "sudo dpkg *.deb", it says "dpkg: error: need an action option". When I searched online I found that this error usually occurs when there is a typing error, which I cannot see in my case....

Comment: I am going senile I think: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` it should be...

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks a lot, now it works :)

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete directions!! Great to hear that now all is well :)